# Put stored procedure result/output into variable

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I have a stored procedure that I'm working with where I'm calling another stored procedure within. The nested procedure accepts a value and returns an ID based on that successfully, but I can't seem to figure out how to cast that result into a variable for another stored procedure in the same wrapper.

Where I am now:

```
P1: BEGIN ATOMIC

CALL GET_ID_BY_VALUE(P_VALUE);

-- want to store output into V_NEW_ID

CALL NEW_PROCEDURE(V_NEW_ID);

END P1;
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Instead of using a `CALL` to invoke the nested SP, can you use a `SELECT ... INTO`?  Something like this: `SELECT NEW_PROCEDURE(V_NEW_ID) INTO MyVariable;`?

Comment: I need the output from the first procedure as V_NEW_ID though. The 2nd proc is just an update so I need the result from the first as V_NEW_ID to use in my 2nd call

Comment: Sorry, I misread that..in that case it would be `SELECT GET_ID_BY_VALUE(P_VALUE) INTO V_NEW_ID;`  I don't know if it will even work on db2, but worth a look.

Comment: @TomN. So, why just not to do `SET V_NEW_ID = P_VALUE;` before the`CALL  NEW_PROCEDURE(V_NEW_ID);` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Arrange for the stored-procedure GET_ID_BY_VALUE to have a second parameter, which is an OUTPUT parameter (and this can be variable V_NEW_ID declared in the scope of your main procedure).

The signature of the GET_ID_BY_VALUE will then be something like `GET_ID_BY_VALUE (IN P_VALUE varchar(...) , OUT V_NEW_ID bigint)`.

When the GET_ID_BY_VALUE sets that parameter V_NEW_ID to some value and returns, the caller has the assigned value accessible in variable V_NEW_ID, which is declared in the caller's scope. The caller can then supply that same variable as an input parameter to `NEW_PROCEDURE( V_NEW_ID)`.

Comment: Will this mess up other calls to the original procedure that aren't passing an output?

Comment: unclear what you mean. If GET_ID_BY_VALUE already exists *as a stored procedure*  (as distinct from a UDF) then your original question should be edited to state its result-set (or how it returns data).